# Moving data from one row to another

Tags: mysql

I'm not quite sure if I'm thinking about this the wrong way, so if that's the case perhaps someone will point me in the right direction. If however I am just missing the concept then perhaps I can get help with that.

So any way I'll win.. or something.

What I want to do is something like this, given a table in a database, in a single query move a specific value to another row.

To clarify take this table as an example:

```
id I value
0 I 5
1 I 2
```

I want to move *value* for *id=0* so that the table become:

```
id I value
0 I 0
1 I 5
```

(OBSERVE! the value at *id=1* doesn't matter, it's overridden and the *id=0* _value_ is just set to zero)

My attempt this far have been a query something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE atable 
SET item = CASE id 
WHEN '1' THEN (SELECT value FROM atable WHERE id='1') 
WHEN '0' THEN '0' 
END;
```

However this is not valid and I can't use the *SELECT* in that fashion. So my take #2 were:

```
UPDATE atable 
SET item=(SELECT value FROM atable WHERE id='1') 
WHERE id='0';
```

Which kind of works, however I can't find a way to then set *value=0* for *id=0*

I hope it all makes sense and aren't all just ramblings now.

Just to try to be all clear:
*I want to **move** the value from one row to another, so copy will not do I can figure that one out. AND I want to do it in one query, of course I could split it up into two queries and it would be simple*

Thank's for your time reading this.

Comment: I doubt that you're going to be able to do this in one query. You need to change values on two rows and I don't think that in a single statement you can control the order in which the rows are updated.

Comment: Do you want to update the value of a row (id) with the value of the next row (id)? Is my understanding correct? id here is the id column.

Comment: I think that is correct, but I also want to remove the value for the next row (id) afterwards. As stated by @TedHopp I believe it might be the case that it's just not a very good idea. But still it feel like a pretty "standard" operation to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help -

```
UPDATE atable a,
(SELECT value, id FROM atable) c
SET a.value = c.value 
WHERE a.id < @MAX(id)
AND a.id = c.id + 1;
```

The only condition is that the id's should be in sequence and you should not have the safe update mode active.

Comment: hmm.. yes, that is interesting. I am leaning toward solving it by either sending an extra parameter (to a php-script running the query) or by adding an extra query to do a two step thingie where I'd 1) copy value from _a_ to _b_ and 2) setting value to zero for _a_. But this actually is very interesting and perhaps even solves my problem...

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing is usually performed in a transaction to make it behave as an atomic operation.  For example:

```
start transaction;    
set @myval = (select value from atable where id = 0);
update atable set value = @myval where id = 1;
update atable set value = 0 where id = 0;
commit;
```

It would be possible to "move" the value from the first row to the other row with a single statement, however it is extremely ugly looking and probably less efficient.  I think the following might do that, but I don't think it would be a good idea.

```
update atable set value = 
      (select x.value from 
            (select value from atable where id = 0) x) 
   where id = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean there, *struggling with understanding it* I guess that is the option I would have to keep it in one query. I did some more thinking and realized that I actually do have the information, just that I wanted to send a parameter less to my php-script. But if nothing else I learned something here, so thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with one query but it is only possible if the ID is expected to be sequencial

```
update a set a.value=isnull(b.value,0) from atable a left outer join atable b on a.id=b.id+1
```

**EDIT**

```
update a set a.value=ifnull(b.value,0) from atable a left outer join atable b on a.id=b.id+1
```

Comment: Ah, yes it could be an option. My problem is mostly that it's a query on a php-server run quite often, not super-often, but often enough to take care that it's as good as possible. I believe I have two options really, either send an extra parameter since the client-side know the information needed or alternatively I'll just query to set the value to zero after the "original query"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I am going with the "easy" solution since I actually do have more information about the problem I don't per say *need* to read it dynamically.

So for my particular problem I decided to solve it like this:

I have these parameters (in php):

```
$fromSlot, $toSlot, $itemID
```

And I want to move `$itemID` from one slot to another.

But since I know the id of the item I may as well just insert that into the `$toSlot` and set the item of `$fromSlot` to zero.

Basically the table has a `slotID, itemID` where `slotID` is the unique key and `itemID` is an id to reference an item in that slot.

My query became:

```
UPDATE `slots` SET item = CASE slotID
WHEN '$fromSlot' THEN '0'
WHEN '$toSlot' THEN '$itemID'
END;
```

This way I don't need to be concerned by the fact that it might first set the `$fromSlot` to zero and then "copy" that zero into `$toSlot`.

I wanted to avoid sending the `$itemID` all together but realized it really isn't a huge problem and as I rather avoid making two queries then sending the extra parameter.

The alternative I suppose would be to skip sending `$itemID` and then first update the `$toSlot` with `UPDATE slots SET item = (SELECT item FROM slots WHERE slotID='$fromSlot')` and then a second query to set the `$fromSlot.item`

This is how I'll solve it.

Any cleaver ideas or whatnot are of course welcome, but I'll mark this as my accepted answer.

If nothing else maybe it help people follow my train of thoughts and understand why I asked (and answered -_-) this question.